# Accepting lambda as function parameter and extracting return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I need to accept lambda function as a parameter and figure out its return type. So far, I couldn't come up with anything workable. Here is the example:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 foo(T2 arg, std::function<T1(T2)> f)
{
    return f(arg);
}

...

int n = foo(3, [](int a){ return a + 2; });   <-- ERROR!
```

How can it be done? Boost solution is OK, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't pass `std::function` as a parameter. It has some overhead because it uses type erasure to store any type of callable, such as function pointers, functors, lambdas (which are just an automatically generated functor), etc. Instead, you should just template the function type. Then you can use a trailing return type to figure out the return type of the function:

```
template <typename T, typename Function>
auto foo(T arg, Function f) -> decltype(f(arg))
{
    return f(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

An `std::function` and a lambda are not the same, they are distinct types. The former is a container that can store any type of *callable* object, while the latter is a callable object. Assigning a lambda to an `std::function` works because `std::function` has a constructor that performs the necessary conversion. But that's not the case with template argument deduction, which requires exact matches, and user defined conversions are not considered. That's why your code fails to compile.

The solution is simple, as Rapptz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356506/241631) states, modify `foo` to take the callable as a template argument.

```
template <typename Arg, typename Func>
auto foo(Arg arg, Func f)
    -> decltype(f(arg))
{
    return f(arg);
}
```